# Php replace exact word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is my problem:

Using `preg_replace('@\b(word)\b@','****',$text);`

Where in text I have `word\word and word`, the `preg_replace` above replaces both `word\word` and `word` so my resulting string is `***\word and ***`.

I want my string to look like : `word\word and ***`.

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong???

**LATER EDIT**

I have an array with urls, I foreach that array and preg_replace the text where url is found, but it's not working.

For instance, I have http://www.link.com and http://www.link.com/something

If I have http://www.link.com it also replaces http://www.link.com/something.

Comment: Is there anything else to go on? Is the word always at the end of the string? Are the previous ones always near a backslash...?

Comment: You probably need `\s` instead of `\b` then, because the backslash is a word boundary too :) of course, `\s` doesn't match at start/end of string though.

Comment: Maybe exploding the $text by a space into an array, then foreach your way through and if the word = word\word leave it else change it to *** maybe?

Comment: Check my last edit. @Chris What if my users try to enter "texttexttext"$url"texttexttext" and there are no spaces?

Comment: It will not be replaced, it would be ignored. Relying on word boundries in that instance wouldn't work. It may pay to clear up your question as it is not 100% clear what you are wanting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively specifying that you don't want certain characters to count as word boundary.  Therefore you need to specify the "boundaries" yourself, something like this:

```
preg_replace('@(^|[^\w\\])(word)([^\w\\]|$)@','**',$text);
```

What this does is searches for the *word* surrounded by line boundaries or non-word characters except the back slash `\`.  Therefore it will match *.word,* but not *.word\* and not `*\word.*  If you need to exclude other characters from matching, just add them inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `str_replace("word\word", "word\word and")`, I dont really see why you would need to use a preg_replace in your case given above.

Comment: He doesn't want to replace `word\wording`

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for he wants to replace all matches except certain word boundaries.

Comment: Yes well, he has edited the question a few times after I added my answer. Not so weird my answer is not helping then is it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that doesn't use a regex. It will ONLY replace single occurances of 'word' where it is a lone word.

```
<?php
$text = "word\word word cat dog";
$new_text = "";
$words = explode(" ",$text); // split the string into seperate 'words'

$inc = 0; // loop counter
foreach($words as $word){

    if($word == "word"){ // if the current word in the array of words matches the criteria, replace it
        $words[$inc] = "***";
    }
    $new_text.= $words[$inc]." ";
    $inc ++;
}

echo $new_text; // gives 'word\word *** cat dog'
?>
```